# How can I get co-ordinate of pattern matched object in image like we get co-ordinate of face when we apply face detection on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, pattern-matching

I have an image with some photo, some data etc.  Image will have a circular object each time as shown in attached file.  I want to get the coordinate of that circular object using JavaScript when I select the image.[Image With Circular Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iusZP.png)

Comment: please share code what you have tried

Comment: I haven't got anything I am asking for any code / plugin which will help to match pattern

Comment: Why someone mark my question as not useful??  If you have something I want then please give it first

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this: 
https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Even if this is not exactly what you are looking for, you can learn how to get coordinates of two elements matching points.

Comment: No.. actually consider one scenario I have One large image white multiple objects in it. I have one small image having small black circle.  Now I want to find the co-ordinates where my small image (having black circle) matches with large image ( may be 0 or more than that match will found)  generally called pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

consider having below html:

```
<pre>
<style type="text/css"> 
.imgA1 { position:absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px; z-index: 1; } 
.imgB1 { position:absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px; z-index: 3; }
</style> 

<img class=imgA1 src="http://full.path.to/imageA.jpg" width="400" id="img1">
<img class=imgB1 src="http://full.path.to/imageB.jpg" width="300" id="img2">
</pre>
```

You can get coordinates and width of each image like this:

```
<pre>var top1 = $("#img1").position().top
var left1 = $("#img1").position().left
var top2 = $("#img2").position().top
var left2 = $("#img2").position().left
var w1 = $("#img1").width()
var w2 = $("#img2").width()</pre>
```

So from here if left position(left2) of small img is smaller than width + left position(w1+left1) then they have a matching point. From there you can go and find exact point of matching.

Comment: No you are just checking image sizes and trying to guess.. I want something that will actually give me coordinates where exact match of one image on other image